# Python failure to find all duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, random

This is related to random sampling. I am using random.sample(number,5) to return a list of random numbers from within a range of numbers contained in numbers. I am using while i < 100 to return one hundred sets of five numbers. To check for duplicates, I am using :

```
if len(numbers) != len(set(numbers)):
```

to identify sets with duplicates and following this with random.sample(number,5) to try to do another randomisation to replace the set with duplicates. I seem to get about 8% getting re-randomised ( using a print statement to say which number was duplicated), but about 5% seem to be missed. What am I doing incorrectly? The actual code is as follows:

```
while i < 100:
    set1 = random.sample(numbers1,5)
if len(set1) != len(set(set1))
    print('duplicate(s) found, random selection repeated')
set1 = random.sample(numbers1,5)
```

In another routine I am trying to do the same as above, but searching for duplicates in two sets by adding the same, substituting set2 for set1. This gives the same sorts of failures. The set2 routine is indented and placed immediately below the above routine. While i < 100: is not repeated for set2.
I hope that I have explained my problem clearly!!

Comment: What do you mean by 5% seem to be missed?

Comment: Ff the hundred returned 'sets', 5 contain duplicates whereas about 8 have re-randomised and are without duplicates as are the other sets

Comment: This is an example of part of the return[3, 10, 10, 21, 26, 41]
[8, 11, 15, 22, 23, 33]
[7, 20, 30, 34, 36, 40]
[14, 28, 30, 33, 35, 46]
[7, 22, 35, 37, 45, 48]
[11, 21, 28, 40, 41, 45]
 duplicate found, random selection repeated
[7, 11, 16, 18, 25, 25]

Comment: Is it perhaps because `if len(set1) != len(set(set1))` is not indented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your code to stop the second sample from having duplicates.  What if you did something like a second while loop?

```
while i<100:
    i+=1
    set1 = random.sample(numbers1,5)
    while len(set1) != len(set(set1)):
        print('duplicate(s) found, random selection repeated')
        set1 = random.sample(numbers1,5)
```

Of course you're still missing the part of the code that does something... beyond the above it's difficult to tell what you might need to change without a full code sample.

EDIT: here is a working version of the code sample from the comments:

```
def choose_random(list1,n):
    import random 
    i = 0 
    set_list=[]
    major_numbers=range(1,50) + list1
    print(major_numbers) 
    while i <n: 
        set1 =random.sample(major_numbers,5) 
        set2 =random.sample(major_numbers,2) 
        while len(set(set1)) != len(set1):
            print("Duplicate found at %i"%i)
            print set1
            print("Changing to:")
            set1 =random.sample(major_numbers,5) 
            print set1
        set_list.append([set1,set2])
        i +=1
    return set_list
```

Comment: the 'do something' part is just to print the 100  set1's. When I tried using a second while statement the 'programme went into a loop printing'duplicate(s) found, random selection repeated' without stop. I had to 'crash the application to stop the looping. I am very new to this so I am doing stupid things. I think that one of the problems is that I did not indent the command for the second randomisation properly if a duplicate was found. Could that cause the routine to 'miss' duplicates?

Comment: Are you sure your scope/alignment is in order? Please paste the exact code you are running in your question.

Comment: def choose_random(list1):
 import random 
 i = 0
 set1 = []
 prev = None
 major_numbers=list(range(1,50))
 major_numbers= list1 + major_numbers 
  
 print(minor_numbers)
 print('\n')
 while i <5:
    set1 =random.sample(major_numbers,5)
    set2 =random.sample(minor_numbers,2)
    for number in set1:
        if prev == number:
           print('duplicated', prev)
           set1 = random.sample(major_numbers,5)
           prev == number
           
       set1.sort()
            
    print(set1)
            i =i + 1
ist1 contains the same numbers as in range declaration to force duplicates

Comment: Click edit on your question and put the code in there--this code is not complete.  What is `minor_numbers`?

Comment: Sorry minor_numbers is a second set of numbers to append to list2 and carry out the same routine as for list1 and major_numbers Couldn't fit the whole thing into the allowed characters. May now be too confusing for anyone to read!

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you Perfect solution. Now on to the next task I have set myself!

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please click the check to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you give obviously has some gaps in it and cannot work as it is there, so I cannot pinpoint where exactly your error is, but running `set1 = random.sample(numbers1,5)` after the end of the `while` loop (which is infinite if written as in your question) undoes everything you did before, because it overwrites whatever you managed to set `set1` to.

Anyway, `random.sample` should give you a sample without replacement. If you have any repetitions in `random.sample(numbers1, 5)` that means that you already have repetitions in `numbers1`. If that is not supposed to be the case, you should check the content of `numbers1` and maybe force it to contain everything uniquely, for example by using `set(numbers1)` instead.

If the reason is that you want some elements from `numbers1` with higher probability, you might want to put this as

```
set1 = random.sample(numbers1, 5)
while len(set1) != len(set(set1)):
    set1 = random.sample(numbers1, 5)
```

This is a possibly infinite loop, but if `numbers1` contains at least 5 different elements, it will exit the loop at some point. If you don't like the theoretical possibility of this loop never exiting, you should probably use a weighted sample instead of `random.sample`, (there are a few examples of how to do that here on stackoverflow) and remove the numbers you have already chosen from the weights table.